# Will Shimano B01S brake pads work with m675 slx

Tags: brakes, shimano

I recently started cycling regularly again after 3 years or so and need to change some parts. It's infuriatingly hard to find information on compatability for parts now that CRC can't sell Shimano stuff. All I get when searching this in Google is 10 different listings from sellers on amazon, eBay, and who knows what else.

Anyway, B01S is half the price of J02A, and I definitely don't need the fins. Does anyone know if B01S will fit on M675 slx brakes?

Comment: Use the correct pads. The brakes are designed for these and you don't want to get involved in an accident or get hurt for saving some cash.

Answer (score 1):

B01S resin pads is one option you have for pads for this model of brake caliper.  If it is longer lasting metal compound pads you seek for the [SLX brakes, Shiimano spec sheet](http://www.shimano-nordic.com/content/cycling-new-zealand/en/home/components11/mountain/slx1/br-m675.html) lists the  F03C as the compatible metal pad.